# GenericCompanion Unapplied

Tags: scala, collections, exception

missing argument list for method apply in class GenericCompanion Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected. You can make this conversion explicit by writing apply _ or apply(_) instead of apply.

```
class ValidationException[A](

  validatedObject: A,

  message: String,

  errors: Set[ValidationError]

)


case class ValidationError(key: String, message: String)


throw new ValidationException(request.price,"message", Set[ValidationError(String,String)])
```

Comment: - you can use 4 spaces before your code to make it show up as code. 
- What exactly is your question?

Comment: i have solve the problem using set.apply(ValidationError(String,String))   thakns all of you

Comment: since you have a solution, please go back and answer your question or "Accept" Tim's answer (assuming he helped you). You will get points for doing this and this question will no longer appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set.apply(ValidationError(String,String))

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of immediate problems with this code:

1. `ValidationException` will need to extend `Throwable` if you want to use it as an exception.
2. The value for `errors` on the last line needs fixing. It should look something like this:

   ```
   throw new ValidationException(..., Set(ValidationError("key", "string")))
   ```

Note that I have replaced `[]` with `()` and put string values in the constructor of `ValidationException` rather than the `String` type.

However neither of these would generate the error that you mention, so there is probably more going on here that is not obvious from this code fragment.